# applying filter to other pages

Tags: python, django, sorting, filtering

i've got sort on main page of shop, it works , but in other pages it doesn't works. How could i apply this sort to other pages(sorted by category etc.)?  at the url address it updates but no result, it just shows items in default order.i tried to find any answer but couldn't

*view*

```
class Shop(ListView):
    template_name = 'essense/shop.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    paginate_by = 9
    allow_empty = True
    model = Item

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        collections = Collection.objects.all()
        brands = Brand.objects.all()

        context['brands'] = brands
        context['categories'] = categories
        context['collections'] = collections

        return context

    def get_ordering(self):
        return self.request.GET.get('orderby', )


class ShopCategory(Shop, ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_ordering(self):
        return self.request.GET.get('orderby', )
```

*template*

```
<div class="product-sorting d-flex">

                                    <p>Sort by:</p>
                                    <form name="selectForm" action="{{request.get_full_path}}" method="get">
                                        <label for="orderby"></label>
                                        <select name="orderby" id="orderby" onchange="selectForm.submit();">
                                            <option value="">default</option>
                                            <option value="price">price: $ - $$</option>
                                            <option value="-price">price: $$ - $</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <input type="submit" class="d-none" value="submit">
                                    </form>

                                </div>
```

*urls*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('shop/', Shop.as_view(), name='shop'),
    path('shop/subcategory/<slug:slug>', ShopBySubCategory.as_view(), name='shop_subcategory'),
    path('shop/category/<slug:slug>/', ShopCategory.as_view(), name='shop_category'),
    path('shop/on-sale', ItemsOnSale.as_view(), name='on_sale'),
    path('shop/brand/<slug:slug>', ShopByBrand.as_view(), name='shop_brand'),
    path('shop/<slug:slug>/', ItemDetail.as_view(), name='single_product')

]
```

*move to categories*

```
<div class="widget catagory mb-50">
            <!-- Widget Title -->
            <h6 class="widget-title mb-30">Categories</h6>

            {% for cat in categories %}
                <div class="catagories-menu">
                    <ul id="menu-content2" class="menu-content collapse show">
                        <!-- Single Item -->
                        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ cat.name }}">
                            <a href="#">{{ cat.name }}</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu collapse show" id="{{ cat.name }}">
                                <li><a href="{% url 'shop_category' cat.slug %}">All</a></li>
                                {% for subcat in cat.category_subcategory.all %}
                                    <li><a href="{% url 'shop_subcategory' subcat.slug %}">{{ subcat.name }}</a></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

*template tag for filter*

```
@register.simple_tag
def url_replace(request, field, value):
    d = request.GET.copy()
    d[field] = value
    return d.urlencode()
```

Comment: Can you show the template code where you move to another page (previous, next, etc.)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated, pls take a look

Comment: but this does not contain any logic to move to the next/previous page.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it works with pagination, i had a template tag for this. i cant filter it on page with items sorted by categories

Comment: very likely that is because the template tag does not retain values of the querystring...